# Is MSE a good place for peer reviews? Is it appropriate to start a bounty for this type?

Tags: discussion

Sorry, I'm not yet a mathematician.

For example, when I solved a problem but I'm not sure whether it's right, is MSE a good place to put a peer-review post for this? If so, what's the suggested behavior? Directly write the solution in the original post or write it as an answer?

As far as I've experienced, sometimes it doesn't draw much attention, then is it appropriate to start a bounty for this? I found a rough case. For example, after you start a bounty, you get an answer like this:

> Yes, I think it's right.

Or just pointing out some minor mistakes, say typos. Is it deserving for a bounty? Or is it an acceptable answer? If I think it's not worthwhile, can I downvote it? The reason for the behavior of downvoting? After all, it's a response.

I want to know the etiquette for this kind of questions.

Comment: If you mean *solving a problem* in the sense *something that could be published*, this seems relevant: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4125/submitting-a-paper-for-review

Comment: If you meant *solving a problem* in the sense solving something akin to exercise or textbook problem, you might have a look at these posts: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/are-please-check-my-proof-type-of-questions-proper and http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/best-way-of-asking-check-my-proof-questions (And maybe some of the questions linked there.)

Comment: I think the etiquette for meta is to ask one question, not eight.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, a dupe to the link you've posted on the second remark. I voted to close.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Well, maybe I didn't express myself well. Essentially there's only one question, but in case that users think that the question is too easy to answer, I remarked some questions to illustrate all the embarrassed cases floating in my mind. Thanks.